# Sorted Day , Month , Year in DataGridView VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I tried to sort data in DataGridView it's not work because function is sort specifically day. Not sort month and year.

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM data_timein WHERE (CONVERT(datetime,day_in,103) >= '" & date1 & "') AND (CONVERT(datetime, day_in,103) <= '" & date2 & "')"

DataGridView1.DataSource = cmd_ExcuteDataTable()
DataGridView1.Sort(DataGridView1.Columns(2),System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)
```

[image]

Comment: What is the data type of your `day_in` column?

Comment: Data type day_in in mysql is varchar.

Comment: Why would you store dates as text in the first place?  The fact that you can't sort the data chronologically is a perfect example of why you should store dates as dates, not text.  Is that something that is within your control?  If so, change it.  If not, you're going to have to convert the data somewhere to another form in order to sort chronologically.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I understand and i will apply for my project. I'm sorry about language usage I'm not good English. I'm from Thailand.

Comment: @allarm Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your English in fine. Your question was understood. Glad to know you are from Thailand. You can add your location to your profile.